# Jetpack Compose: customize the inner textfield within TextField component

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I have custom total textfield like this

[image]

Where 1 - textfield component outline; 2 - inner textfield ouline; 3 - trailing icon or suffix (for material 3 component)

As you can see, the inner text box has a starting extra border and an ending extra border. It fill whole legth of textfiled component now.

I would like to make like this (some kind of "wrap_content" for inner textfield):

[image]

Is there any way to customize the inner borders of BaseTextField or do I need to dive deep into Compose and create my own textbox from scratch?

---

My TotalTextField code:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun TotalOutlinedTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = if (singleLine) 1 else Int.MAX_VALUE,
    minLines: Int = 1,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
) {
    val textColor = textStyle.color.takeOrElse {
        colors.textColor(enabled).value
    }
    val mergedTextStyle = textStyle.merge(TextStyle(color = textColor))

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        modifier = if (label != null) {
            modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {}
        } else {
            modifier
        }
            .background(colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value, shape)
            .defaultMinSize(
                minWidth = TextFieldDefaults.MinWidth,
                minHeight = TextFieldDefaults.MinHeight
            ),
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = readOnly,
        textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(colors.cursorColor(isError).value),
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        minLines = minLines,
        decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
            TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = value,
                visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                placeholder = placeholder,
                label = label,
                leadingIcon = leadingIcon,
                trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
                singleLine = singleLine,
                enabled = enabled,
                isError = isError,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                colors = colors,
                border = {
                    TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox(
                        enabled,
                        isError,
                        interactionSource,
                        colors,
                        shape
                    )
                },
                contentPadding = textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
                    top = PADDING_8.dp,
                    bottom = PADDING_8.dp,
                )
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the compose and material version you are using? I am getting deprecated errors and some fields/methods are internal.

Comment: Compose UI, Tooling, Foundation etc: 1.4.3, Material: 1.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the source code of `TextField`,
In `internal fun TextFieldLayout`, we can see that the `prefix`, `suffix`, `leading`, and `trailing` are all placed inside a `Layout` by calculating placement internally. There are no direct options to override them from the component level.

To achieve the given UI,
You can use a `Row` with the required background color and have the `BasicTextField` and the trailing composable as children and align them as required.

[image: Screenshot]

**Sample code**

```
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Companion.LightGray) // TextField background color
        .defaultMinSize(
            TextFieldDefaults.MinWidth,
            TextFieldDefaults.MinHeight,
        ),
) {
    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min),
        ... // Properties
    )
    trailingIcon?.invoke()
}
```

Comment: thx a lot. It's working!